# Blessed "Prompt" is black on black by default - how do I style it?

Tags: javascript, blessed

I am using [blessed](https://github.com/chjj/blessed) and I am trying to add a prompt to my application. It works fine, but I can't read its text. I have prepared a minimal example, that illustrates, what I see.

**I would like to know how I can style the text in the inputs.** The [style-Attributes as mentioned in the docs](https://github.com/chjj/blessed#style) seem to have no effect.

Here's what I see (there is text in the input and on the two buttons, but it is black on black).

[image]

Here's code that reproduces the error on Debian 9 with standard terminal and standard theme:

```
var blessed = require('blessed');
var screen = blessed.screen({});

var prompt = blessed.prompt({
    left: 'center',
    top: 'center',
    height: 'shrink',
    width: 'shrink',
    border: 'line',
});

screen.append(prompt);

screen.key(['q', 'C-c'], function quit() {
    return process.exit(0);
});

screen.render();

prompt.input('Search:', 'test', function() {});
```

Comment: Hats off for the minimal example - hard to come across one of them these days.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Disclaimer: I'm not very familiar with the `blessed` codebase, so there might be a more native way of doing this. If there isn't, then it sounds like this feature should be requested / implemented.*

#### Observation 1 - Your terminal's color settings are contributing to the problem

Based on the screenshot you gave, your terminal's default colors have a black foreground against a white background. If you invert this in your terminal settings, you should be able to see the expected behavior.

But! Your application should no matter what the user's settings are, so that isn't a good solution...

#### Observation 2 - The `Prompt` constructor hardcodes it's children with a black background

When in doubt, go to [the source](https://github.com/chjj/blessed/blob/eab243fc7ad27f1d2932db6134f7382825ee3488/lib/widgets/prompt.js)! Here is part of `prompt.js` as of 2017-09-30:

```
// ...
function Prompt(options) {
  // ...
  Box.call(this, options);

  this._.input = new Textbox({
    // ...
    bg: 'black'
  });

  this._.okay = new Button({
    // ...
    bg: 'black',
    hoverBg: 'blue',
  });

  this._.cancel = new Button({
    // ...
    bg: 'black',
    hoverBg: 'blue',
  });
}
// ...
```

So, it seems like the only way to fix your issue is to overwrite these children's style properties after the `Prompt` has been created.

#### Solution 1 - Overwrite child style properties after creation

After you create the prompt, you can overwrite the style of each child. It's probably most straightforward to just make the foreground white (as it should be)...

Also, for maintainability's sake, this hack really should be in it's own function.

```
function createBlessedPrompt(options) {
    var prompt = blessed.prompt(options);

    // NOTE - Not sure if blessed has some sortof `children()` selector.
    //        If not, we probably should create one.
    //        Nevertheless, temporarily hardcoding the children here...
    //
    var promptChildren = [prompt._.input, prompt._.okay, prompt._.cancel];

    promptChildren.forEach(x => {
        Object.assign(x.style, {
            fg: 'white',
            bg: 'black'
        });
    });

    return prompt;
}
```

#### Solution 2 - Submit a bug fix to the blessed repository

This really seems like an issue with blessed itself. If you can think of a way that `Prompt` should properly handle this case, you should totally help your fellow coder and write an issue / pull request that fixes this.

Good luck!

Comment: the workaround in Solution 1 works, which is great. I will also follow your recommendation to make this an issue with blessed itself. Thank you!

Comment: I took your advice and at least raised it as an issue: https://github.com/chjj/blessed/issues/315

Comment: I figured i'd just go for a pull-request, too. Didn't look too hard. https://github.com/chjj/blessed/pull/316

Comment: @amenthes nice! Hope your PR pulls through. I wonder what a more robust solution would be? I feel like someone should be able to easily set the children's style... Maybe I'm just used to CSS ;)

Answer (score 1):

I tried this sample on Win 10 and Ubuntu 16. The only change I made to your code is `screen` definition has been moved before the `promt` definition (without it I got 'No active screen' error), and also I added styles according to the documentation. My repro:

1) run `npm install blessed` inside an empty folder

2) create `index.js` in that folder with the following code

```
var blessed = require('blessed');
var screen = blessed.screen({});

var prompt = blessed.prompt({
  left: 'center',
  top: 'center',
  height: 'shrink',
  width: 'shrink',
  border: 'line',
  style: {
    fg: 'blue',
    bg: 'black',
    bold: true,
    border: {
      fg: 'blue',
      bg: 'red'
    }
  }
});

screen.append(prompt);
screen.key(['q', 'C-c'], function quit() {
  return process.exit(0);
});

screen.render();
prompt.input('Search:', 'test', function() {});
```

3) run `node index`

4) got

[image]

Is that want you wanted?

Comment: This does not work for me either. I now believe that this is due to the gnome terminal's color scheme. I'll open an issue on their tracker.

Comment: Thanks for catching the ordering problem. I changed the question accordingly.